# CSS media query with em Chrome

Tags: css, google-chrome, media-queries

I have discovered a kind of weirdness. I'm developing a new web project and am planning to use em's as units in media queries. However, I put together a little test and found a very weird thing in Chrome.

You can take a look at the full page Codepen here: http://codepen.io/pentzzsolt/full/bAdJr
Editable code here: http://codepen.io/pentzzsolt/pen/bAdJr

Now, the media query simply switches the background color of one of the  tags, no big deal. When you zoom in, you see the color change, but when zooming out, in Chrome, it doesn't change back, only when you zoom back one level less to the original. Then, if you are zooming in again, you need to go 3 levels up related to the original, then 2 levels lower, etc... I hope you understand. Point is, it follows some sort of a pattern.

In Firefox, however, it works as would be expected: at the breakpoint, if you zoom in, switches color, you zoom out, switches back.

Any ideas why this could happen? I sniff something is wrong with using only min-width only in the media query, I haven't fully wrapped my head around these parameters yet.

Comment: Can you provide the html and css?

Comment: The code can be seen here:

http://codepen.io/pentzzsolt/pen/bAdJr

Edited the post and added it as well.